# How do you directly interface with hardware from Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, low-level, bios

So, I decided to learn Assembly Language for the 80x86 this summer. I picked up four books on assembly. So far I've read the first two and I'm half way though the third one and I think I understand everything that has been presented. I've written a few Hello World programs as well as other little exercises from the book and I feel very comfortable with the language.
However, there is one thing that none of the books have addressed so far and it's the thing that I'm most interested in. That is, How do you address the hardware directly from assembly language? So far in the books the author has used system calls, jumps to specific functions in memory, and interrupts, but these methods rely on software already present in the system.

I'm writing my programs using NASM and loading them into an old Pentium I computer. I'm not using any OS right now, just the BIOS. I guess what I'm trying to do is write my little OS that is autonomous and does not rely on the BIOS (except for initial boot). Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could start at [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you booting and running your code with BIOS only?

Assuming you really are only using BIOS, or even if you were using DOS that would be okay.  You simply address the hardware, specify the address of some hardware register right in the instruction or put that address in a register and do a register indirect read or write.

Access to hardware is only difficult when an operating system is in the way, making the hardware do something useful of course is much easier with an operating system, naturally.

Fortunately the BIOS has enumerated the pci(e) hardware, that is the PC way of doing things, so you can use some DOS utilities I think to find out how the hardware has been enumerated.  Another "PC way of doing things" the PCI(e) address for the hardware is also the x86 address, the two address spaces overlap, so once you get the PCI(e) address for some peripheral then you can use that address in your code.  naturally since the pcie window is relatively small for things like video you still have to page through the peripheral memory, but that is peripheral specific not a PC or x86 thing.

if your motherboard has a serial port/uart that would be the best place to start with directly accessing hardware.

Even better would be to use a simulator pcemu or other, rather than start on hardware, depending on your choice of simulator you may have much better visibility into what is going on and a peripheral like a uart may be even that much simpler as you might not have to initialize it just start throwing bytes at it (until you learn more).

Comment: if you want to write your own little OS, assembly is a bad choice, do it like everyone else mostly C with a little assembly where absolutely necessary.  Same answer, doesnt matter on language, you want to access hardware directly just do it, read/write to the address.  DOS is a good choice as a development operating system as it is enough of an operating system to get you going but also trivial to get out of the way if you want to bypass it.  For a long time Windows was simply a DOS program that at some point stops making dos calls. (linux could/can be launched that way as well)

Comment: After reading Rienhard's answer I strongly suggest that since you dont already know the answer to your own question (you did ask it publicly) then you should look for something like pcemu, open source, 80x86 instruction set simulator with BIOS and DOS capabilities, something you can build on but at the same time have a chance at debugging while you pass through this educational phase and work your way up.   Video, hard disk, usb are all going to be major months to years learning experiences to do what you appear to be trying to do.  start as simple as you can get away without major failure.

Comment: To boot I just write my assembled code into the first sector of a floppy disk using a program called HxD. The bios loads it automatically. Now, how do you figure out the address of the hardware that you want to interface with? Is it written on a manual? Is it the same for all PCs or does it vary from machine to machine? And can you give me a tiny code example or a link to an example of how this is done? Thank you very much!

Comment: depends, some things like the serial ports may have legacy support to the old days where it was somewhat static and I think the bios controls that.  other stuff is on pcie and enumerates and even on the same machine sometimes shows up at a different place, so you have to ask the pci controller where everything is, which is why I suggested just letting dos do that initially since there are some dos utilities that just dump that information out.

Comment: @dwelch: Sorry, I simply forgot to +1 your answer, done now. Thanks for this good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

dwelch is completely right, but I want to answer your question on a more basic level:
In most cases, you access hardware via control and status registers. In the most simple case e.g. you want to read from a serial line, and you are waiting for a new character to arrive. A status register could set a bit "ready", and then you read the character from another register.
This means you have to address registers like memory addresses. Again in most cases this is done by mapping registers to you address space, i.e. the registers have memory addresses in an address range where no memory is, e.g. the topmost addresses. Then you can use most instructions that access the memory, e.g. load and store.
In the real world the situation is more complex, because the CPU uses virtual addresses that are mapped to the physical address space (where the registers are located) by a programmable memory management unit.